# Static compile openSSL

Tags: openssl, static-libraries

I am a newbie in Linux, but need somethings doe, so I am trying to get things done.
I need to have a openssl static compilesd for a proprietary linux distro at as virtually no tools to build packages.
I come across a post which explained how to do that.

```
cd /tmp
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1e
./config

I then Added "-static -static-libgcc" to the CFLAG line of openssl- 
1.0.1e/Makefile (Note this was AFTER I ran ./config). Then I built it like 
normal.
```

All goes well until this point. I don't have any package-root and I understat that is an example, but what do I write in its replacement to compile openssl ?

make INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/openssl-1.0.1e install ??
i don't have a install, just install.com or INSTALL

```
make INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/package-root install
it is now statically compiled

$ ldd /tmp/package-root/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl
not a dynamic executable
```

Thanks